# Does adding new dedicated circuits involve new breakers at the panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

An electrician is planning on doing some work in a few weeks and I want to make sure I am educated to make sure it is done right too.

Circuits need to be added so some of my appliances are on their own. I have plenty of room in my panel, so I would assume this would require running new wire to the panel and installing a new 15 or 20-amp circuit, depending on my needs. So, the extra/empty circuit spots in my box would be used?

Does this sound correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the electrician is going to add circuits then yes he will add breakers in the extra spaces in your panel.